# SQL Server 2012 Installation Error on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008, sql-server-2012-express

I am facing an error while trying to install SQL Server 2012 EXPRESS ADVANCED EDITION(32bit) on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise(64bit).

After passing Rule Check, at `install updates` section, error occurs about update could not be downloaded. On clicking next, following error in dialog box occurs.

```
SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

Setup encountered a failure while running job UpdateResult.

Error code 0x876E0003.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this issue while installing sql server management studio, what i did was unchecked the option of "**Include Sql Update in this feature**" while installing the first time and i got this error.

So next time i let it remain checked and disconnected the internet for few seconds(i was connected to internet if you are not then no need) till i got the error as "Could not check for updates..." after that closed the error popup window.
I was able to install, hope this helps.

This was the cause of the error i was facing and as described i solved this.

Comment: Note that there is a `/UpdateEnabled` parameter available if you are trying to run this headlessly. You can set it to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error while installing SQL Server 2014. I solved it using a solution provided in this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0800ccf-5ade-471c-8942-b7d43031478b/sql-2012-installation-error?forum=sqlgetstarted).
To sum it up:

1. Go to a folder named "x64" or "x86"
2. find a file named "DefaultSetup" and edit it Notepad or other editors.
3. Add a line and type "UpdateEnabled=False" below "[options]"
4. Run installer again

Comment: it worked for me thanks , SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

When saving file "DefaultSetup.ini" with error, you are not allowed to save it in the same "x64"  folder, and if you come across such an error like me and you are not allowed to save it, you should save this file "DefaultSetup.ini" in another place like Desktop and then in sql server installation in the 'Advance' section. Click the "install based configuration f" option and select the new file you saved to proceed with the next steps of the installation.